# Browser keeps downloading CSS background image

Tags: css, performance, google-chrome, download

Browser keeps downloading my svg background image. It's a CSS animation that is looping on my website.

I've made a screenrecording to show the issue: https://share.getcloudapp.com/L1uzRzRo

It's not that big of an issue since the svg is cached. However, it kinda looks weird with site fully loaded +1000 seconds

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
body:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image: url(https://www.turbotobias.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Fly-med-banner-TurboTobias-Graphics2.svg);
  background-position:center;
  background-size:400px auto;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  animation:slideLeft 5s linear infinite;
  
}


@keyframes slideLeft {
  from {
    transform:translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform:translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this not to be an issue with code but rather a problem with VS code localhost... Whenever I took the code to live server environment the issue was resolved.